# Git pull fails and sometimes causes introducing external changes but sometimes it just asks to commit changes firstly

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I try to keep git history linear by avoiding excess merge commits. For that reason when I want to commit new changes firstly I try to `git pull` and then call `git commit`. (btw I don't want to use `git rebase` command)

But `git pull` often fails because of conflicts and I faced two cases:
1) Git suggest to stash or commit my changes before doing `git pull` - in this case I agreed to firstly commit and then call `git pull`.
2) Git pulls external changes and my working tree becomes polluted: my changes are mixed with external ones - *and that makes me suffer*.

**The question is**: why sometimes git choose option #1 but sometimes #2?
Is there a way that git would always choose case #1?

If it matters I use TortoiseGit.

Comment: "*I don't want to use `git rebase` command*" What?! Why?

Comment: You should definitely be using `git rebase`. It allows you to have a more linear history and eliminates merge commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisegit-users/RDJF7Q0Sbss) describes the case similar to option #2:

*Thing is, files get pulled anyway and end up being flagged as local modifications which is not the case. We then need to manually revert files that are not modified by the user.*

As I understood, all because of error **fatal: unable to write new index file, git did not exit cleanly**. If one happen, `git pull` will end up with option #2. Otherwise, option #1 (if merge conflicts exist).